# how do I compile just wireless drivers in kernel?

Tags: kernel, compiling

I have patched a file for my wifi driver in  *net/wireless/drivers/zd1211rw/*, and I couldn't get it to compile just that driver. so I backed up into the main directory of my linux kernel source, and issued the command `make modules`.  It is taking forever, even though I have a quad core, so is there any way I can tell it specifically to just compile the wireless drivers?  or even just zd1211rw?

Thanks.  I have 3.2.0.

Comment: the majority of the procedure is documented here: http://www.codewhirl.com/2012/04/how-to-compile-a-single-module-in-ubuntu-linux/ if anyone wants some easy rep

Comment: hum so I just tried it, and it is not what I am looking for.  Because when I get to the command `make EXTRAVERSION=-21-generic O=/usr/src/mytree modules SUBDIRS=scripts` it starts at the beginning, and compiles every single module [starting with arch/], which is what I am already doing now.  Thanks anyway though.  My modules are still compiling, and it has reached the zd1211rw folder, but so far there is no .ko file, just an zd1211rw.o file.  I guess it makes .ko's at the end?

Comment: iirc you can skip that line

Comment: Thank you, that linked showed me how to do it; I answered my own question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up for compiling:

```
extraversion="-"$(uname -r|sed 's/[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]-//' ) # extraversion in 3.5.0-17-generic is -17-generic
mkdir ~/tmp/build/
cd ~/tmp/build/
cp /boot/config-`uname -r`  .config
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0$extraversion/Module.symvers ./
cd /usr/src/linux-source-3.5.0/
make EXTRAVERSION=$extraversion O=~/tmp/build oldconfig
make EXTRAVERSION=$extraversion O=~/tmp/build prepare
make EXTRAVERSION=$extraversion O=~/tmp/build outputmakefile
make EXTRAVERSION=$extraversion O=~/tmp/build archprepare
make EXTRAVERSION=$extraversion O=~/tmp/build modules SUBDIRS=scripts
```

Now you are ready.  To compile module put in the folder of its location.  For zd1211

```
make EXTRAVERSION=$extraversion O=~/tmp/build/ modules SUBDIRS=drivers/net/wireless/zd1211rw
```

cd into ~/tmp/build/drivers/net/wireless/zd1211rw/ to find the .ko file.